# jest and react-test library (...).toBeVisible is not a function

Tags: reactjs, jestjs, react-testing-library

My unit test for react component throw error even if debug print the correct result.

TypeError: expect(...).toBeVisible is not a function

```
debug(screen.getByText('contains'))
expect(screen.getByText('contains')).toBeVisible();
```

this print:

```
console.log
      <div
        class="sc-jOhDuK iDFeaX"
      >
        contains
      </div>
```

I can't figure out the reason why toBeVisible is not a function even if debug print the correct result.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will need to import or require in your individual test file.

```
import '@testing-library/jest-dom';
```

or

```
require('@testing-library/jest-dom');
```

For example:

```
import { render, cleanup, screen } from '@testing-library/react';
import '@testing-library/jest-dom';
```

Answer (score 2):

You might be missing `@testing-library/jest-dom` in your package.json file:

```bash
npm i -D @testing-library/jest-dom
```

If it is present, then you need to `require` it in your jest setup to be able to use `toBeVisible`:

```js
require('@testing-library/jest-dom');
```

Comment: My project is not a typescript project.

Comment: OK, I edited my answer to reflect this.

Comment: debug print the element correctly. It means jest and react-test-library configured correctly and screen.getByText() function works

Comment: The element was present all along. What was missing was the `toBeVisible` function. Also you should require/import `@testing-library/jest-dom` in your jest setup file so that you won't need to remember putting it in any new test.

Answer (score 0):

I use `PNPM` and installing with `pnpm add -D @types/testing-library__jest-dom` worked for me.